# Fuzzballs vs. black holes

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, string-theory

Now I am trying understand:

**What are [fuzzballs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzball_(string_theory))?**

**What is the difference between fuzzballs and black holes?**

According to [this](https://www.theorie.physik.uni-muenchen.de/activities/schools/archiv/asc_school_2018/mathur-3.pdf) presentation, one can construct fuzzball solution from ordinary BH solution in few steps:

1. Start with standart metric, for example Schwarzschild metric:

$$
ds^2 = - \left(1-\frac{r_0}{r}\right) dt^2 + \frac{dr^2}{1-\frac{r_0}{r}} + r^2 (d\theta^2 + \sin^2 \theta d\phi^2)
$$

2. Make the analytic continuation $t \to -i \tau$

$$
ds^2 =  \left(1-\frac{r_0}{r}\right) d\tau^2 + \frac{dr^2}{1-\frac{r_0}{r}} + r^2 (d\theta^2 + \sin^2 \theta d\phi^2)
$$

3. Let the direction be a circle $0\le \tau \le 4\pi r_0$ and add time:

$$
ds^2 =  - dt^2 + \left(1-\frac{r_0}{r}\right) d\tau^2 + \frac{dr^2}{1-\frac{r_0}{r}} + r^2 (d\theta^2 + \sin^2 \theta d\phi^2)
$$

4. Dimencionally reduce on the circle $\tau$, and obtain 3+1 dimensional metric in $(t,r,\theta, \phi)$ coupled to  scalar field $\Phi$:

$$
g_{\tau\tau} = e^{\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \Phi}
\;\;\;\;\;
\Rightarrow
\;\;\;\;\;
\Phi = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \ln (1-\frac{r_0}{r})
$$

$$
g^E_{\mu\nu} = e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\Phi} g_{\mu\nu}
$$

$$
ds^2_E =  - \left(1-\frac{r_0}{r}\right)^{1/2} dt^2 + \frac{dr^2}{(1-\frac{r_0}{r})^{1/2}} + r^2 \left(1-\frac{r_0}{r}\right)^{1/2}(d\theta^2 + \sin^2 \theta d\phi^2)
$$

This is solution of Einstein equations with scalar field as source:

$$
T_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu \Phi \partial_\nu \Phi - \frac{1}{2} g^E_{\mu\nu} \partial^\mu \Phi \partial^\nu \Phi
$$

$$
T^\mu_{\;\nu} = diag (-\rho, p_r, p_\theta , p_\phi) =  diag (-f, f, -f , -f)
$$

$$
f = \frac{3r_0^2}{8r^4(1-\frac{r_0}{r})^{3/2}}
$$

This construction looks very unnatural. Could someone explain me motivation of such strange construction?

**Is the fuzzball simply solution of Einstein eqyuation with matter or more complex object?**

Comment: Fuzzballs are solutions to supergravity field equations. The critical observation about them is that an outside observer could not distinguish them as bing different from black hole solutions except that fuzzballs solutions have structure at its horizon. For overviews and reviews I recommend arxiv.org/abs/1205.0776 and arxiv.org/abs/1207.5431 respectively; for the possible relevance of the fuzzball program to the black hole information paradox arxiv.org/abs/0810.4525 is a nice reference.

Comment: A nice set of lectures on the fuzzballl paradigm is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jgdnRnkB1DE and a recent critique to the implications of the program for the information paradox can be seen in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EHd17SVum58. I recommend you to see the video on the critique because it explains how the construction of your question can be understood as a cylindrical geometry that pinches off at the horizon of the black hole (giving rise to structure at the horizon).

Comment: As an aside comment. Fuzzballs are consistent backgrounds in string theory, that's a fact. The problem is that the philosophical questions concerning their very existence or importance are wide open. Because of that, it's very difficult that you really get the sense that the construction is really natural or even needed, nobody truly understands. See the excellent blog post [Fuzball civil war in india](https://motls.blogspot.com/2018/04/fuzzball-civil-war-in-india.html) .

Answer (score 2):

Ramiro Hum-Sah comments answer well your question, but I will elaborate a bit more.

Fuzzballs are solutions of the equation of motion in string theory, that is specific configurations of strings and branes. Working in full non-perturbative string theory or M-theory is usually not feasible (yet) and anyway we may be interested in the 4D low energy description. That is why Fuzzballs are usually presented as solution of Supergravity (SUGRA), that is the low energy limit of string theory. Dimensionally reduced in 4D SUGRA appears as a gravity solution with additional vector and scalar fields, similarly to the example you mention.

The concrete difference between a fuzzball and a black hole in 4D is that while the black hole has no hairs, the fuzzballs have a non trivial multipole expansion, violating the no-hair theorem (and solving the information paradox). A fuzzball is expected to behave more like a star than a hole, meaning that it can exchange matter and information with the outside, like any other object.

Comment: Wonderful answer @Rexcirus ! Your second paragraph on why fuzzballs are cited as SUGRA solutions is simple excellent and pertinent.  Just a minor comment on your equally great last paragraph. Is not an established fact that fuzballs solve the information paradox; it's not even clear if fuzzballs are relevant for the experience of the infalling observer (see [A critique to the fuzzball program](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.10616)).

Comment: I meant to say, fuzzballs claim to solve it. I do agree that the problem is far for settled.

Comment: My intuition is that working in the SUGRA approximation will not be enough to establish the correctness of the fuzzball proposal, especially regarding the counting of microstates.

Comment: Exactly @Rexcirus, I agree. The SUGRA approximation is not enough to establish the correctness of the proposal or even its actual relevance for the information paradox. The existence of such "exotic" class within string theory is a wide open problem.

Comment: Thank you for answer! Is it true, that no-hair theorem is working in SUGRA, but isn't working in String theory?

Comment: The no hair theorem is formulated in 4d gravity, so it's a theorem about the low energy limit of string theory. String theory would use a completely different language made of strings and branes.

Comment: @Nikita One simple way to understand why the no-hair theorem does not work in string theory is simply to recognize that the hypothesis of the theorem are not satisfied wihtin string theory. Orientifold planes violate the condition of the strong positivity of the energy, some configuration of anti-branes and ghost branes do the same. Fuzzballs are not the only "hairy" solutions you can find in string theory. See [Half-flat Quantum Hair](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.4557) for another interesting example.